# How to verify text using xpath when there is no locator there

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

**Validation Error Text :**

The e-mail address test@ is not valid.

Html Code :

```
<div class="msg error">
<h2 class="element-notvisible">Error message</h2>
The e-mail address <em class="placeholder">test@</em> is not valid.</div>
```

Here I want to get validation message text based on some common text. For ex: "Based on The e-mail Address" OR "is not valid".

I tried xpath :

```
//class[contains(text(),'is not valid')]
//class[contains(text(),'The e-mail')]
```

How can I create xpath for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
//div[
    @class='msg error' 
    and contains(., 'The e-mail address')
    and contains(., 'is not valid')
]
```

Or if you need to test only text nodes that is direct child of the `div`, you can do this way :

```
//div[
    @class='msg error'
    and text()[contains(.,'is not valid')]
    and text()[contains(.,'The e-mail')]
]
```

Comment: It might be but value **test@** will change every time as I am testing so many diff. values for email id. so at that time will it throw error?

Comment: @HelpingHands I just realized that, updated the answer accordingly